# After Effects ExtendScript how do I detect if the project needs saving?

Tags: extendscript, after-effects

I'm using ExtendScript .jsx scripts to automate a few things in After Effects.  It gives me a lot of control, but I can't obviously see whether there's a property of app or app.project which tells me if the open project has edits since its last save.  My script needs to know this to decide whether to automatically save to a new file if there are edits, or keep with the current file if there aren't.

Comment: InDesign Documents have a boolean property called `modified`. Do After Effects Projects have something similar? I do not have the After Effect API to hand.

Comment: I can think of only one way that you can do it, but it's not 100%: Save it to a tmp location and compare the size of the files. I actually always create new file, I don't care of about lot of aep files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a look into the [After-Effects-CS6-Scripting-Guide.pdf](http://blogs.adobe.com/creativecloud/files/2012/06/After-Effects-CS6-Scripting-Guide.pdf). Looks like there is no flag that tells you if project needs saving. So the answer is: No.

Answer (score -1):

For future developers - yes it is possible:

1. if you want to check if the project was saved initially:
   just check app.project.file if it is null then the project doesn't exist on the computer, if it shows path it means it was saved at least once
2. app.project.dirty gives you information if the project was modified but not saved. "Dirty" projects will have an * in the project window title.
3. additionally, use app.project.file.modified to see when the project was saved last time

Evgenii